# Post to server in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

1)Find the GPS Value send to server each and every time.
2)Now i want to store it on SQLite DB and then send to server with multiple
parameter in a single post to server.
My question is which one is efficient either (1) or (2)
Which one consumes more battery power etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second is always the best, as you don't have to do Post multiple times, and it's efficient! You can send it as a payload like JSON or XML, with all the data in one shot.